# Should I supply external libraries with a CMakeLists.txt or supply find_packages instead?

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I am working on a project that needs some external libraries. Since it is meant to be cross platform, I am using cmake.

What is the preferred way when distributing such projects? Should I supply the external libraries (such as zlib) with their own `CMakeLists.txt` or should I signal the dependency by simply supplying `find_packages()`?

the former provides all things needed. while the latter let's the developer decide how to supply the dependency (vcpkg for example)

Comment: "What is the preferred way when distributing such projects?" - There is no universally-preferred way. If is up to you, whether you build external libraries as a part of your project (thus providing `CMakeLists.txt` for them) or you use `find_package` to locate that libraries. I have seen a project which supports both approaches and lets the user select between them.

Comment: Note that there may be some legal obligations for you to "supply external libraries", if this is legal at all. You should definetly consult the licenses of those projects. If you're able to reliably make `find_package` work, it's simplest to use this option, but if this is not possible or not possible on all target systems, you may be able to use [the FetchContent module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) as fallback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althoug there is no *universally* preferred approach, I absolutely believe you should stick to `find_package`. Declare your dependencies like this:

```
find_package(Pkg [version] REQUIRED [components])
```

Include `[version]` and `[components]` only if you know `Pkg` itself provides first-party CMake package configuration files. If you are writing and distributing a library, you will include equivalent `find_dependency` calls in your `MyProjConfig.cmake` file.

If some dependency does not have a standard CMake find module or provide its own CMake package configuration file, you should write your own in `./cmake` and add `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")` to the root `CMakeLists.txt`, before any `find_package` call. You will install your find modules, too, and include the same addition to the module path in your config files.

Inside the find module, you can use whatever approach you want to create some imported targets for your dependencies. Using `PkgConfig` is a good approach here.

Going through `find_package` instantly works with a number of dependency providers: vcpkg, the `cmake_paths` Conan generator, Linux distro system packages, and so on.

---

The primary alternative to doing this is to vendor the code, meaning including your dependencies in your build directly, whether through copy/paste into your source tree, a git submodule, or by build-time download from the internet (`FetchContent`).

The mechanism used to build these is nearly always `add_subdirectory` in the end, which pulls your dependencies' CMake builds into yours.

Perhaps the biggest issue with this is that most projects' CMake code is totally unprepared to be used in this way. It might trample your cache variables, inject invalid flags into your targets, overwrite your generated headers, and so on. Integration is a nightmare.

Also, from a software distribution standpoint, doing this ties your code to particular versions of your dependencies and takes control away from others who might want to package your code. For instance, Debian packages are not allowed to bundle their dependencies... if `libA` depends on `libB`, then each gets its own package. With `find_package`, it is trivial for a maintainer to inject the appropriate dependencies into your build. Without, it typically involves a difficult-to-maintain patch.